# Can I pass value of forward declared enum?

Tags: c++, enums, c++11, forward-declaration

When passing forward declared struct or a class, one has to pass it to a function through a reference or a pointer.

But, what can be done with a forward declared enum? Does it also have to be passed through a reference or a pointer? Or, can it be passed with a value?

Next example compiles fine using g++ 4.6.1 :

```
#include <iostream>

enum class E;

void foo( const E e );


enum class E
{
  V1,
  V2
};

void foo( const E e )
{
  switch ( e )
  {
    case E::V1 :
      std::cout << "V1"<<std::endl;
      break;
    case E::V2 :
      std::cout << "V2"<<std::endl;
      break;
    default:
      ;
  }
}

int main()
{
  foo( E::V1);
  foo( E::V2);
}
```

To build :

```
g++ gy.cpp -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++0x -O3
```

Is the above standard compliant, or is it using an extension?

Comment: Your code would work equally well with a forward-declared class: `struct A; void foo(A); struct A {}; void foo(A) {}` is valid code. See [When to use forward declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/q/553682/20984).

Comment: What you could have tried is *define* (and not *declare*) `foo` before defining `E`.

Comment: @LucTouraille The 1st link tells it all (thanks). For the 2nd thing, I know that I would get `error: 'V1' is not a member of 'E'` errors with the reason, but this would compile fine : `void foo( const E e ) { std::cout << (int)e<<std::endl; }` if you put it before defining the enum.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A declared enum, even if you don't specify the enumerators (what the standard calls an *opaque-enum-declaration*) is a complete type, so it can be used everywhere.

For completeness, here's a quote from paragraph 3 of §7.2:

> An *opaque-enum-declaration* is either a redeclaration of an enumeration
>   in the current scope or a declaration of a new enumeration. [*Note:* An
>   enumeration declared by an *opaque-enum-declaration* has fixed
>   underlying type and is a complete type. The list of enumerators can be
>   provided in a later redeclaration with an enum-specifier. *—end note* ]

And the grammar for *opaque-enum-declaration*, from paragraph one of the same §7.2:

> *opaque-enum-declaration:*
>
> > *enum-key attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> identifier enum-base<sub>opt</sub>*`;`

Comment: And that's why opaque-enums always have a fixed underlying type (`int` if not explicitly set): because this way it size is fixed without depending on the values of the constants.