# Is It Valid To Return Forward Declared Enum Class? (Visual Studio 2015 Linker Error)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, language-lawyer, c++14

I have an issue where the following code compiles on GCC (4.8+ tested) and Clang (3.4+ tested) but does not compile on Visual Studio 2015 (VC++ 14.0).

Foo.h:

```
#include <functional>

namespace Error {
enum class Code;
static const Code None = static_cast<Code>(0);
}

class Foo{
public:
  std::function<Error::Code()> Run();
};
```

Foo.cpp

```
#include "Foo.h"
#include <iostream>

std::function<Error::Code()> Foo::Run() {
  return [&]() {
    std::cout << "hello\n"; 
    return Error::None;
  };
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "Foo.h"

namespace Error {
enum class Code {
  None = 0,
  Error = 1,
};
}

int main() {
  Foo foo;
  foo.Run()();
}
```

The resulting error in VC++ 14.0 is as follows:

```
Foo.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "enum Error::Code __cdecl std::_Invoke_ret<enum Error::Code,class <lambda_813e82254384ef384f6a5fe34e885f01> &>(struct std::_Forced<enum Error::Code,0>,class <lambda_813e82254384ef384f6a5fe34e885f01> &)" (??$_Invoke_ret@W4Code@Error@@AAV<lambda_813e82254384ef384f6a5fe34e885f01>@@@std@@YA?AW4Code@Error@@U?$_Forced@W4Code@Error@@$0A@@0@AAV<lambda_813e82254384ef384f6a5fe34e885f01>@@@Z)
```

Which I believe is an internal std library function for implementng `std::function`.

This code is similar to usage of an internal library I'm trying to use that shares a standard program interface for tools, but forward declares Error Codes so they can be customized.  I believe this should be valid code based on §7.2 (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911188/can-i-pass-value-of-forward-declared-enum))  The enum, though forward declared, should be a complete type and usable as a return value.  Here is the relevant bit in the standard:

> An opaque-enum-declaration is either a redeclaration of an enumeration in the current scope or a declaration of a new enumeration. [Note: An enumeration declared by an opaque-enum-declaration has fixed underlying type and is a complete type. The list of enumerators can be provided in a later redeclaration with an enum-specifier. —end note ]

Is this code valid?  If so, is there a work around to get VC++ to accept it?

Comment: _"The enum, though forward declared, should be a complete type and usable as a return value."_ Forward declarations don't provide _complete types_ enum or not.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's why this is technically not a forward-declaration but an opaque-enum-declaration (if there even is a proper definition of the term "forward-declaration"...) In any case, such a declaration introduces *a complete enumeration type*. There's a special case for enumerations, IIRC to never introduce incomplete enumeration types.

Comment: your `enum class Code` _definition_ is not in the same namespace as your _declared_ `enum class Error::Code`

Comment: What happens if you define and use proper enumerators within the lambda, instead of `None`? Did you compile with `/Za`? Did you try to explicitly specify the underlying type?

Comment: @inetknght Sorry, that was a re-typing mistake for the minimal example, putting it in the namespace does not fix the issue.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ In the answer I linked, the standard would appear to say otherwise (referring to opaque-enum-declaration).  I've added the relevant standard quote to my question.

Comment: @dyp If I define the enum within the same translation unit as the lambda, it appears to work, even if its definition conflicts with that of the real implementation.  This will function as a work around, so thanks for the idea!  Though I'm still curious if this is a true bug in Visual Studio.

Comment: I think it's clear from your quote that the code is correct and therefore it must be a VS bug. Suggest filing a VS bug report and removing language-lawyer tag

Comment: Code encapsulation question: Why are you implementing Error::Code in main.cpp? It's obviously part of Foo.h/cpp - and Foo.cpp has no direct visibility into main.cpp.  It seems odd.  It would be like having a socket class and defining all the error codes near your main() entry point & not in the socket class files.

Comment: @JasonDeArte The actual library helps implement some callback signals, so the enumeration is for maintaining a consistent callback signature.

Comment: I've just played around a bit with this issue on VS2015U1. It still appears if you use a proper class instead of the lambda, explicitly specifying the return type on the lambda, using `return {}` instead of `return Error::None`, moving everything into one source file. The crucial point, as Sam Cristall has noticed, is the lack of a definition of the enumeration (even a definition with no enumerators is sufficient). Once that definition is there, no linker issue occurs. I agree with @M.M this is a VS bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the code is valid.

This certainly does appear to be MSVC bug. I am able to reproduce this with a simple code sample;

func.cpp

```
#include <functional>
enum Code : int;
Code func2();
void func()
{
    std::function<Code()> f2 { func2 };
}
```

main.cpp

```
enum Code : int {
    Some = 0,
    Error = 1,
};
Code func2() { return Some; }
int main() {}
```

The error remains;

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "enum Code __cdecl std::_Invoke_ret(struct std::_Forced,enum Code (__cdecl*&)(void))" (??$_Invoke_ret@W4Code@@AEAP6A?AW41@XZ@std@@YA?AW4Code@@U?$_Forced@W4Code@@$0A@@0@AEAP6A?AW41@XZ@Z) referenced in function "private: virtual enum Code __cdecl std::_Func_impl,enum Code>::_Do_call(void)" (?_Do_call@?$_Func_impl@P6A?AW4Code@@XZV?$allocator@H@std@@W41@$$V@std@@EEAA?AW4Code@@XZ)

The error hints at an instantiation issue with `std::function<Code()>`, but no amount of explicit instantiation in either translation unit offers any resolution.

The error also does not seem dependent on the un-scoped `enum` vs. the scoped `enum class`.

*The only work around at this time appears* to be not using an opaque enum declaration at all, but to supply the full enum with its enumerators.

---

From Microsoft Connect (2016-05-09);

> A fix for this issue has been checked into the compiler sources. The fix should show up in the future release of Visual C++.

Comment: Thanks.  I found as a work around you can also supply a "wrong" enum definition to the translation units that can only see the opaque declaration.  This is obviously a hack though.

Comment: @SamCristall : That's not a hack, that's an ODR violation. I.e., it's not a workaround, it's UB.

Comment: @ildjarn I don't think hack is a very well defined term!  But thank you for the warning.  It appears to be working for what I need and fortunately isn't for production code.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some more observations too large for a comment:

This is indeed a compiler bug, not a bug of the Standard Library implementation. The following program reproduces the same issue on VS2015 Update 1 without using the StdLib:

```
template<class T>
T create() {
    return {};
}

enum class Code;

int main() {
    create<Code>();
}
```

The linker complains about an unresolved symbol:

`enum Code __cdecl create<enum Code>(void)`

- The linker issue disappears if you leave out the return value (replace `T` with `void`).
- The problem remains when explicitly specifying the underlying type.
- The problem remains if we replace the scoped enumeration with an unscoped enumeration. We do not have to specify the underlying type when using Microsoft's C++ extensions (`/Ze`). Nothing changes when specifying the underlying type.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should declare **None** in header (.h) and define it in source file(.cpp)

Foo.h

```
namespace Error {
    extern const Code None;
}
```

Foo.cpp

```
namespace Error {
    const Code None = static_cast<Code>(0);
}
```

Sometimes enum will be optimized and will have no instance or address, especially you declare it as a **static** variable.